# multiple images upload to database using a function

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to understand how to do this multiple image upload thing for a few days now and i cant figure it out. Im quite new to this so please don't be mean. I checked several websites before actually asking for help here.

THIS IS THE PAGE WITH THE FORM

```
<?php
require_once("photoalbum-common.php");
require_once "lib/dbutils.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/actors-styles.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css'>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$pdo = connect();
if ( isset( $_POST['formid']) && $_POST['formid'] == 'fileupload') {
$photoid = addPhotograph( $pdo, $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], 'self', $_FILES['images']);

    }

?>

<div class='w3-container w3-center'>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="link">Add images</button>
</div>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
  <div class="w3-modal-dialog">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <a href="" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</a>

        <h2>Upload photograph</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <form action='?' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='photoform' class='w3-container'>
          <div class="w3-group">
<!--            <input type='file' name='uploadfile' class='w3-input'> -->
            <label class="w3-label">Image file</label>
        <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple class='w3-input'/>

          </div>
          <div class="w3-group"> 
            <label class="w3-label">Name</label>  
            <input type='text' name='name' class='w3-input' required>

          </div>
          <div class="w3-group">  
            <label class="w3-label">Description</label> 
            <textarea name='description' class='w3-input' required></textarea>

          </div>
          <input type='hidden' name='formid' value='fileupload'>
          <input type='submit' value='Upload' id='uploadbutton' class='w3-btn'>
        </form>
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p></p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

HERE ARE THE FUNCTIONS INSIDE photoalbum-common.php

```
 function addPhotograph( $pdo, $name, $description, $user, $fileinfo) {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO photographs ( `name`, `description`, `user`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->execute( array( $name, $description, $user));
  $photoid = $pdo->lastInsertId();

  $tmp_name = $fileinfo["tmp_name"];
  $name = $photoid."_".$fileinfo["name"];
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE photographs SET `image`=? WHERE `photoid`=?");
  $stmt->execute( array( $name, $photoid));
  $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$name");
  return $photoid;  
}



function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}
```

The second function i got it from http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php, unfortunately, i did not manage to make anything work. The best i could come up with was to show two uploads without the actual images displaying as they were not uploaded to the database.

If someone can help me or guide me how i can upload multiple images using the above as the current contents only work for one image upload. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you have set file array and do code with single file.

Please make it correct with below code:

```
if(!empty($fileinfo)){
    $total_files = count($fileinfo['name']);        
    for($i = 0 ; $i<$total_files ; $i++)
    {
        $tmp_name = $fileinfo["tmp_name"][$i];
        $name = rand()."_".$fileinfo["name"][$i];
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$name");
    }
}
$tmp_name = $fileinfo["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: tried to use your code inside the addphotograph function but it still uploads just one image.